# What is the ModifiableWindowsApps folder and can I delete it?

Tags: windows-10, files-folders

I noticed a folder `ModifiableWindowsApps` inside the "Program Files" folder. What's odd is that this folder appeared on two of my non-primary drives, that is, drives other than C (where windows is installed and which has the normal "Program Files" folder). They have modified date in summer of 2019. But this folder did not appear on another non-primary drive so not sure what the criteria is for it to be installed on a drive. The owner is a user or group called `TrustedInstaller`. Attempting to delete the file as an administrator does not work.

What is this folder? Why does this folder appear on non-primary drives? Is it safe to delete and, if so, how (perhaps change the owner)?

Answer (score 4):

For an answer see the article
[ModifiableWindowsApps folder shows up in Windows 10](https://www.windowslatest.com/2019/07/20/modifiablewindowsapps-folder-in-windows-10/):

> According to [UWP guidelines document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/uapmanifestschema/element-desktop6-mutablepackagedirectory), the ‘ModifableWindowsApps’ folder may contain installation files that would allow users to install mods for games. Microsoft says the function is intended to be used by certain types of PC games and developers can specify one or more subfolders for their games.

The Microsoft document contains further details:

> Specifies a folder under the `%ProgramFiles%\ModifiableWindowsApps` path where the contents of your desktop application's install folder are projected so that users can modify the installation files (for example, to install mods). This element is currently intended to be used only by certain types desktop of PC games that are published by Microsoft and our partners.

So this is a Microsoft folder, as evidenced by its owner being
`TrustedInstaller`.
It is created by certain Microsoft game(s) that you have installed.
It is totally legitimate and can be left where it is,
as there does not seem to exist any mechanism for moving it to another disk.

Comment: So it is a bug or why is it installed on other drives?  It looks like Windows created "Program Files" folders on non-primary drives that only have "ModifableWindowsApps" folder? That's mainly what bothers me, I'm fine to leave the folder on the primary drive.

Comment: This "feature" is apparently in development, so may in the future allow more control than is possible today. For the moment, I suppose that the folder is allocated on the disk with most free space, which is exactly the wrong place. Your only recurse is to file a bug report in the Feedback Hub.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove it, change the folder ownership under to Everyone (under Right Click, Properties, Security, Advanced), then add full permissions to Everyone under properties, and then you should be able to delete.

Comment: when i go to add the `full control` permission it is grayed out for all groups and user names.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. You have to go to the advanced part and in there you can add permissions to full control

Comment: Thanks Sander, and Select a principal - Everyone first.